# Add a column in mysql table with random timestamp

Tags: mysql

I want to add a new column in an existing mysql table with default value of random timestamp. Random timestamp should be anything between (now + 3 hours) and (now +3.5 hours). I used below sql command and it's giving error:

```
alter table latency_adjustment_rules 
add column expiration_timestamp TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) + FLOOR(RAND() * 3600)) + 10800
```

Error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ FLOOR(RAND() * 3600)) + 10800' at line 1

Can someone please suggest what's wrong with my mysql statement?

Comment: You can do this as part of the insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would achieve this with a [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) on insert:

```
DELIMITER \\
CREATE TRIGGER latency_adjust
BEFORE INSERT ON latency_adjustment_rules
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.expiration_timestamp IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.expiration_timestamp = NOW() + INTERVAL (FLOOR(RAND() * 3600) + 10800) SECOND;
    END IF;
END\\
```

I created a small demo example on [rextester](https://rextester.com/QMVWG94493).

Comment: Thanks for helping with the example. But my expiration timestamp cant be null. If I specify it to be non null, then I will have to specify some default value for it and now() cant be default value as I want expiration to be now()+ 3 hourss In that case, how do I add trigger?

Comment: @Priyanka although my column definition will allow the column to have a `NULL` value, the trigger will ensure that it never is `NULL`. See my updated [demo](https://rextester.com/IOS23997) you can choose to insert no expiration time or a value, either way a value is inserted into the column and it never ends up being `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a default value that way. The best thing you can do is use a TRIGGER instead. Check the manual for examples.

You will also need to check how to specify time intervals. You probably want to use Unix timestamps (MySQL timestamps are in the former 2018-10-10 23:14:37 and cannot be incremented by adding seconds, you would need to use DATE_ADD for that)

Comment: There are existing data in the table for which I want to have random expiration times only at the first time while adding the column. Can you please give example of DATE_ADD?